# How to consolidate or summarize the metrics's status within PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, metrics

Basically, would be interesting to create more sophisticated view of the scorecard !. e.g. in order to get a snapshot of the number of sub metrics in "On Track" status. Also, to construct additional views like **heatmap** using the status in scorecard.

[image: Scorecard view]

PBI has visualization to import a metric from scorecard but it can extract only 1 task or sub task at a time. Since our goal is to summarize the number of status types per metric/goal, there is no option currently.

[image: PowerBI default possibility for scorecard]

In the example above, there are only 3 metric **(Lavender, marigold,Teal)** and max. 3 sub-metrics **(Task1,task2....)** hence easy to track but **what if** there are 30 metrics and each have 10-20 sub metrics with their own statuses.

e.g. Let's say Lavendar has 30 sub-metrics

1. 10 sub-metrics which are in *On-Track* status
2. 12 in *AtRisk* status
3. 5 in *Not Started* status
4. 3 in *Off-track* status

**In such cases, consolidated view is necessary. Wondering how to build one within PowerBI ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PBI doesnt have a default way to create such view, **we could save the data from the Flow in a sharepoint list** using *Get item* at the end of the Flow.
Within PBI, we can use **Get data** from *sharepoint list* which can be used to visualize the data !